# how to convert the date of this type (5/24/2018) to 2018-05-24 using regular expression with javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

i have a date 5/24/2018 i need to convert that to following format [yyyy-mm-dd] 2018-05-24. how to i do that with javascript regular expression

Comment: Why is using a regular expression required in this case?

Comment: i need to send date to the server of  [yyyy-mm-dd]  but my datepicker in react app giving me date of  [m/dd/yyyy] of this format

Comment: i am new to javascript, i have been lookin for help almost 2days but i found no solution

Comment: If you aren't obligated to use Regex, read about `Date()` class, it will make what you need without any problem

Comment: Try using the `Date` object: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Comment: **Don't use `Date`**. Though it supports mm/dd/yyyy format in practice, I believe it is not standard. And for your specific use you can use trivial `.split('/')`, so even a regex is an overkill, unless you want validation as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you like to use regular expression you can do the following:

```js
function parseDate(str) {
  var match = str.match(/^(\d{1,2})\/(\d{1,2})\/(\d{4})$/);
  var y = match[3];
  var m = match[1] < 10 ? `0${match[1]}` : match[1];
  var d = match[2] < 10 ? `0${match[2]}` : match[2];
  return `${y}-${m}-${d}`;
}
console.log(parseDate('5/24/2018'));
```

I advice you send data to the server as timestamp in milliseconds (`new Date().valueOf()`). It's easy to work with it.

Comment: that is really very helful, that you so much.

Comment: in my case the database has date in that format that is why i need  exactely in such format. and thank you once again

Answer (score 0):

Why you want to used regular expression? , just make like the following

```
function formatDate(date) {

      var day = date.getDate();
      var month= date.getMonth();
      var year = date.getFullYear();

      return year+ '-' + month + '-' + day;
    }

    console.log(formatDate(new Date("5/24/2018")));  // show current date-time in console
```

Comment: thanks  you, but in my case the date comes from date picker